# Cant write correct queryset in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

i have three models:subplan,subplanfeature and price.I wanna show gym price table,but it shows wrong result

```
class SubPlan(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class SubPlanFeature(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
  
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Price(models.Model):
    gym=models.ForeignKey(Gym,on_delete=CASCADE)
    subplan=models.ForeignKey(SubPlan,on_delete=CASCADE,related_name='subplans')
    feature=models.ForeignKey('SubPlanFeature',on_delete=CASCADE,related_name='features')
    price = models.IntegerField()
    highlight_status = models.BooleanField(default=False,null=True)
```

here is my view

```
def pricing(request,slug):
    gym=models.Gym.objects.get(slug=slug)
    price=models.Price.objects.all()
    banners=models.Banners.objects.filter(gym=gym)
    plans1= models.Price.objects.filter(gender='man',gym=gym)
    dfeatures1=models.Price.objects.filter(gender='man',gym=gym)
    return render(request, 'pricing.html',{'plans1':plans1,'dfeatures1':dfeatures1,'gym':gym})
```

and template here

```
 <thead>
        <tr>
          <th style="width: 34%;"></th>
          {% for plan in plans1 %}
          <th style="width: 22%;">{{plan.subplan}}</th>
          {% endfor %}
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        
        {% for feature in dfeatures1 %}
        <tr>
          <th scope="row" class="text-start">{{feature.feature}}</th>
          {% for plan in plans1 %}
          <td>
            
           {{plan.price}} Azn.
            
          </td>
          {% endfor %}
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
      </tbody>
```

it should display as this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35K0w.png)

but shows this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkWfA.png)

what should i change?

Answer (score 0):

you can use "forloop" counter in template

```
    ...        
    {% for feature in dfeatures1 %}
    <tr>
      <th scope="row" class="text-start">{{feature.feature}}</th>
      {% for plan in plans1 %}
      <td>
       # only print when counter in parent loop are the same
       {% if forloop.parentloop.counter == forloop.counter %}
          {{plan.price}} Azn.
       {% endif %}
      </td>
      {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: it shows price only one,but i need it to show 'one per week' or 'a month' once